# Service cannot be started. System.IO.IOException: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, registry

I want to create a dependency on service through the registry, in On start method I am calling a method which I can create a dependency in a registry.The below is the code.

But I am facing some exceptions while using it, someone please help me to resolve this issue.

```
    protected override void On Start(string[] args)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        serverDependency();

        int.TryParse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["IntervalTime"].ToString(), out intervalTime);

        // Dynamically create new timer
        System.Timers.Timer timScheduledTask = new System.Timers.Timer();

        // Timer interval is set in miliseconds,
        // In this case, we'll run a task every minute
        timScheduledTask.Interval = (intervalTime) * 1000;

        timScheduledTask.Enabled = true;

        // Add handler for Elapsed event
        timScheduledTask.Elapsed +=
        new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timScheduledTask_Elapsed);
    }

    public bool serverDependency()
    {
        string ServiceName = "MySQL";
       // BinaryFormatter bm = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("POSAgent");
        if (reg != null)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey("POSAgent");
        }
        reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("services");
        if (reg != null)
        {
            reg = reg.OpenSubKey("POSAgent");
            reg.SetValue("DependOnService", ServiceName, RegistryValueKind.MultiString);
        }
        else
        {
            reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("POSAgent");
            reg.SetValue("DependOnService", ServiceName, RegistryValueKind.MultiString);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The below is the exception

> Service cannot be started.  System. IO. IO Exception : The parameter
>   is incorrect.
>
> at Microsoft . Win 32 . Registry Key. Win 32 Error(Int 32 error
>   Code, String    str)    at Micro soft. Win  32. Registry Key .Create
>   Sub Key (String sub key, Registry Key Permission Check permission
>   Check, Registry Security registry Security)    at Microsoft .Win 32.
>   Registry Key. Create Sub Key(String sub key)    at POS Agent Service.
>   POS Agent. server Dependency ()    at POS Agent Service. POS Agent. On
>   Start(String[] args)    at System .Service Process. Service Base.
>   Service Queued Main Call back(Object state)

Comment: IOException is a documented exception for CreateSubKey: "The nesting level exceeds 510 -or- A system error occurred, such as deletion of the key, or an attempt to create a key in the LocalMachine root."  The latter is exactly what you are doing.  Create app-specific keys inside the Software subkey.   Note how "services" is wrong too, that key exists inside HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet.  These keys should be written by the service installer, not by OnStart.